# Unwanted textview's bitmap outline

Tags: android, opengl, canvas, bitmap, textview

I am trying to get bitmap from TextView like this:

```java
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
}
```

But *returnedBitmap* contains bitmap of TextView with unwanted outline, see [picture from Android Studio Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TQcd.png). Also I tried using the same function but applied *returnedBitmap* on ImageView, and it doesnt have such outline. I don't understand how this can be fixed.

**UPD.**
My TextView layout:

```xml
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/bitmaptext"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="4dp"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      tools:text="test"
      tools:textColor="@color/white" />
```

**UPD2.**
Here is sample project: https://github.com/khoben/test-android, bitmap itself has an outline, but in ImageView doesnt. I need an image without this outline.

**UPD3**. I want to draw bitmaps from texview on video, but [outlining ruins all plans (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCSd8.jpg).

**UPD4**. I should say that problem appeared when image from `getBitmapFromView()` drawn on video thru OpenGL and the cause was incorrect blending mode. [Link to detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67016643/8811167).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the black border of the image in the Android debugger came about because the semi-transparent pixels around the letters and default blending option give black color in result (glClearColor was set to black color). Also OpenGL doing the same.

Here are some tips with OpenGL:

1. Adjust the blending parameters (in my case works):

   ```java
   GLES20.glEnable(GL_BLEND);
   GLES20.glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
   ```
2. Make sure that overlay was drawing on your background, e.g. not on a cleared FBO's background.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your **TextView** in "**getBitmapFromView**".

```
  public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly the same result

Comment: Add your textview in layout, design that layout then pass that layout to this function.

Comment: try this:   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/canvasView"          
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp" 
        android:background="@color/black">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TEXT"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
           /> </RelativeLayout>

Comment: i added xml markup at the question. Here is sample project https://github.com/khoben/test-android, https://github.com/khoben/test-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/twitphoto/photo/grid/imagefromlayout/MainActivity.java#L36 if here set breakpoint you can see bitmap directly in debugger